# XSLT - adding condition to exclude repeated tags

Tags: xml, xslt

I have questions on transforming below xml using xslt,

need to add logic in xslt, such as if 'TERM_DUE_DATE_FROM_PS' is of current month include only that `<G_INV_TERM>....</G_INV_TERM>` in xml. Currently the xml repeats G_INV_TERM 3 times, so based on the condition i want to display only once.

Please help, below is the sample xml:

```
<LIST_G_INV_TERM>
    <G_INV_TERM>
            <HEADER_SALES_ORDER>1125093</HEADER_SALES_ORDER>
            <TERM_SEQUENCE_NUMBER>1</TERM_SEQUENCE_NUMBER>
            <SHIP_DATE_ACTUAL>01-JUL-16</SHIP_DATE_ACTUAL>
            <SHIP_VIA>UPS 123</SHIP_VIA>
           <WAYBILL_NUMBER>0</WAYBILL_NUMBER>
            <PURCHASE_ORDER_NUMBER>NET_30_TESTING</PURCHASE_ORDER_NUMBER>
         <TERM_DUE_DATE_FROM_PS>31-JUL-16</TERM_DUE_DATE_FROM_PS>
    </G_INV_TERM>
   <G_INV_TERM>
         <HEADER_SALES_ORDER>1125093</HEADER_SALES_ORDER>
         <TERM_SEQUENCE_NUMBER>1</TERM_SEQUENCE_NUMBER>
         <SHIP_DATE_ACTUAL>01-JUL-16</SHIP_DATE_ACTUAL>
         <SHIP_VIA>UPS 123</SHIP_VIA>
         <WAYBILL_NUMBER>0</WAYBILL_NUMBER>
         <PURCHASE_ORDER_NUMBER>NET_30_TESTING</PURCHASE_ORDER_NUMBER>
         <TERM_DUE_DATE_FROM_PS>31-AUG-16</TERM_DUE_DATE_FROM_PS>
        </G_INV_TERM>
   <G_INV_TERM>
         <HEADER_SALES_ORDER>1125093</HEADER_SALES_ORDER>
         <TERM_SEQUENCE_NUMBER>1</TERM_SEQUENCE_NUMBER>
         <SHIP_DATE_ACTUAL>01-JUL-16</SHIP_DATE_ACTUAL>
         <SHIP_VIA>UPS 123</SHIP_VIA>
         <WAYBILL_NUMBER>0</WAYBILL_NUMBER>
         <PURCHASE_ORDER_NUMBER>NET_30_TESTING</PURCHASE_ORDER_NUMBER>
         <TERM_DUE_DATE_FROM_PS>30-SEP-16</TERM_DUE_DATE_FROM_PS>
        </G_INV_TERM>
</LIST_G_INV_TERM>
```

output: current month JUL, so display

```
   <G_INV_TERM>
            <HEADER_SALES_ORDER>1125093</HEADER_SALES_ORDER>
            <TERM_SEQUENCE_NUMBER>1</TERM_SEQUENCE_NUMBER>
            <SHIP_DATE_ACTUAL>01-JUL-16</SHIP_DATE_ACTUAL>
            <SHIP_VIA>UPS 123</SHIP_VIA>
           <WAYBILL_NUMBER>0</WAYBILL_NUMBER>
            <PURCHASE_ORDER_NUMBER>NET_30_TESTING</PURCHASE_ORDER_NUMBER>
         <TERM_DUE_DATE_FROM_PS>31-JUL-16</TERM_DUE_DATE_FROM_PS>
    </G_INV_TERM>
```

we are using XSLT 2.0

Thanks

Comment: "*if 'TERM_DUE_DATE_FROM_PS' is of current month*" And if it isn't? -- Please state if you're using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 - and if XSLT 1.0, which processor. XSLT 1.0 of itself does not know what the current date is.

Comment: we are using  XSLT 2.0

Answer (score 0):

EXSLT definitely has `set:distinct()` function which excludes repeating nodes.

Should be supported by vitrually every XSLT 1.0 processor out there.

http://exslt.org/set/index.html

Unfortunately it's not obvious what you're trying to accomplish. If you only want one matching element, it would be `[1]`:

```
//G_INV_TERM[TERM_DUE_DATE_FROM_PS = '30-SEP-16'][1]
```

perhaps in the form of:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="//G_INV_TERM[TERM_DUE_DATE_FROM_PS = '30-SEP-16'][1]"/>
```

Comment: "*Should be supported by vitrually every XSLT 1.0 processor out there.*" Perhaps it should - but it most certainly isn't. Anyway, the question is about something else, IMHO. You may have noticed that the three `TERM_DUE_DATE_FROM_PS` values in the given example **are** distinct.

Comment: @michael.hor257k then asker can definitely use the snippet I've provided.

Comment: No, I don't think so. The next XML might not contain `30-SEP-16` at all. In fact, I am quite certain that documents produced three months from now won't. And the ones that do (such as the given example) contain it only once - so your addition of `[1]` accomplishes nothing.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that, the condition should be something like - if  TERM_DUE_DATE_FROM_PS belongs to current month then display ,   for eg: 1st xml , <G_INV_TERM>            <HEADER_SALES_ORDER>1125093</HEADER_SALES_ORDER>
        <TERM_SEQUENCE_NUMBER>1</TERM_SEQUENCE_NUMBER>
            <SHIP_DATE_ACTUAL>01-JUL-16</SHIP_DATE_ACTUAL>
            <SHIP_VIA>UPS 123</SHIP_VIA>
           <WAYBILL_NUMBER>0</WAYBILL_NUMBER>
            <PURCHASE_ORDER_NUMBER>NET_30_TESTING</PURCHASE_ORDER_NUMBER>
         <TERM_DUE_DATE_FROM_PS>31-JUL-16</TERM_DUE_DATE_FROM_PS>
    </G_INV_TERM>

Comment: @rslin Please don't post code in comments - edit your question instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:variable name="current-month" select="concat(('JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AUG', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC')[month-from-date(current-date())], '-', substring(xs:string(current-date()), 3, 2))" />

<xsl:template match="/LIST_G_INV_TERM">
    <xsl:copy-of select="G_INV_TERM[ends-with(TERM_DUE_DATE_FROM_PS, $current-month)]"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This will copy only the `G_INV_TERM` element whose `TERM_DUE_DATE_FROM_PS` falls in the current month (the month of the transformation).

If there's no such element, the result will be empty. If there are two or more such elements, they all will be copied, resulting in an ill-formed XML document.